# why does the macro run incorrectly in a different workbook? multiple copy of a picture in email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

the code below loops thru all pictures in a sheet and paste each picture in an email body, it works correctly on my workbook, another user used the code below and the result on his end is pasting multiple copies of the same picture in the email body

the workbook of the other user has 2 pictures, when the code is ran 1 picture paste correctly but the other picture is pasted 3x, the user has sent me the workbook and it does show the incorrect result

i copied the 2 pictures on my workbook and it has the correct result

i also sent my working workbook to the other user and on his end it now shows an incorrect result which paste multiple copies of a picture, my workbook on my end has still the correct result

does anybody have any idea why this happens different results for different workbooks?

```
Sub SendEmailWithPicture()
    Dim doc As Object, x, signature, xMailBody2, xMailBody1
    Dim shp As Shape

    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display
        signature = .HTMLBody
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        xMailBody1 = "<BODY>Hi Joe, <br><br>This is the first paragraph<br><br></BODY>"
        
        .HTMLBody = ""
        
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If Left(shp.Name, 3) = "Pic" Then shp.Copy
        
            x = doc.Range.End - 1
            doc.Range(x).Paste
            
            x = doc.Range.End - 1
            doc.Range(x) = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Next shp
        
        xMailBody2 = "<BODY><br>Thank you for your assistance. <br> <br>" & _
                     "Best regards,</BODY>"
        
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody1 & .HTMLBody & xMailBody2 & signature
        
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "My subject"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The first change you should investigate is to properly qualify the sheet to be used (i.e. don't use Activesheet).  You may also benefit from installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and paying attention to the code inspections.

Comment: @freeflow i actually have rubberduck installed but not yet knowledgeable to use more efficiently

Comment: That's to your credit.  Do you know how to generate the code inspections?

Comment: @freeflow tried the code inspection but it inspect all the sub procedure in all open vbaprojects, i filtered with the sub name above and all its says is that the sub is publicly implicit and the sub is not used, tried also using `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes` but still the same result

Comment: `If Left(shp.Name, 3) = "Pic" Then shp.Copy` If the name is not Pic* then the following code will still run and it will still paste. I suggest you wrap the copy-paste code in an If-End If block.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem using `ActiveSheet` as long as it's *explicit* - `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` signals *intent* to use the active sheet, whereas `Range("A1")` is *implicit* and could be a mis-understanding...

Comment: Try adding something like `Debug.Print shp.Name, shp.TopLeftCell.Address()` inside the loop and compare the outputs between "working" and "problem" PC's.

Comment: @CDP1802 you were correct, i figured it out, the workbook of the other user has 2 buttons and since the code to copy-paste was not inside the if-endif block it would paste as you have said. putting the copy-paste doc.range inside the if-endif block fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as told by CDP1802, the fix was putting the copy-paste doc.range in the entire if-endif block

```
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If Left(shp.Name, 3) = "Pic" Then 
               shp.Copy
        
               x = doc.Range.End - 1
               doc.Range(x).Paste
            
               x = doc.Range.End - 1
               doc.Range(x) = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
             End If
        Next shp
```